Optional sampling theorem for a continuous martingale with two bounded stopping time
My question is related to this one, in which it claims that if $X$ is a martingale,$\tau\ge\sigma$ are two bounded stopping times, then $$\mathbb E[X_\tau|\mathcal F_\sigma]=X_\sigma$$
I know one variation of optional sampling theorem, which states that for uniformly integrated continuous martingale the formula above holds. How can we prove by using boundedness of stopping times and without the u.i. condition?
I attempt to use the fact that $X_{t\wedge \tau}$ is a martingale, but I do not know how to pick the filtration.

I found the answer on my own just 25 minutes after posting. I would like to share it here.
Solution: Suppose $\tau\le C$. Let $Y_t=X_{t\wedge C}$. Then I claim:
(1) $(Y_t)$ is u.i and a martingale with respect to the natual filtration of $(X_t,t\ge 0)$.
(2) Apply the optional sampling theorem on $Y_t$ with $\tau$ and $\sigma$, we get $E[Y_\tau|\mathcal{F}_\sigma]=Y_\sigma$. Notice $C$ is the upper bound of $\tau$ and $\sigma$. The proof is done.
The proof of $Y_t$ being a martingale is actually not trivial, so I just take it for granted here. $Y_t$ is u.i. since $E[X_B|\mathcal{F}_t]=X_t=X_{t\wedge B}$, and a family of random variables of the form $\{ E[X|\sigma_i]\}_{i\in \mathcal{A}}$ are u.i.
